# How to login with youtube data api v3

Tags: java, import, youtube-api, authorization

I am currently trying to use the [youtube data api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs) with java. After testing I ran into a few issues.
I tryied out the code example from the [Snippet Page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets?apix=true) but 2 imports are not up to date anymore and i can't find an alternative.

```java
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
```

In the samples this line needs it:

```java
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

So i basically need a way to login to youtube.

Comment: [Offical sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/java)  [Client library samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/master/clients/google-api-services-youtube/v3)  you could copy the authorization section from [Google analytics api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-java) and just replace the api part with the YouTube sample.    If any of these samples are out of date you should report it using the feedback option so that they know to fix it.

Comment: This uses the same code with the AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp & LocalServerReceiver (also same imports for that) so sadly does not help me

Comment: If you believe they are out of date then you should report them as i mentioned.  Google will then know they need to be fixed .  It appears there may already be some note on the issue forum about it already.  [HttpServer artifact in addition to Jetty](https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/issues/434)

Comment: yes, reported it.

Comment: I pinged someone directly at google see if they can get it sored. I dont know enough about Java to help.

Comment: What about the drive sample?   https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java  My google contact says you just need to send feedback to tell them they are broken.

Comment: I sent feedback and the drive is the same^^